# Lambda expression for getting a table row and update the row in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am trying to update my DB table and from my model I am getting the id

```
public void Update(Abc model)
        {
            //Database Table Instance  
            Abc a=new Abc();

            //Trying to update the column where id =id         
            try
            {
                a.id = model.Asset.id;
                a.column = "R";
                db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
```

It set the column to R bt sets Nulls for all other columns because I am not getting values for other columns from model. One way is to set the hidden values in model and send the model but the table has about 30 columns. so I want to get the table row from database where id=id and the only updatte the column in that row in my function in repository .....

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this first you need to get the actual object from your db context and then change the desired property and save it to in database like below:

```
try
{
    Abc a = db.Abcs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.id == model.Asset.id);
    a.column = "R";
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

This will fix your concern.

Comment: Could you please answer another lambda expression on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595922/left-join-in-linq-joining-5-tables-in-left-join